# How to automatically save changes to my backup database in my phpmyadmin?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

How do you link 2 databases if whatever I will do in my database 1 will effect in my back-up database, so that whatever happen in my db1, I have still a backup in my db2

Answer (score -1):

In phpmyadmin, click on the database that you want to back up. Go to the export tab, and export it.

Then, click on the database you want as the back up. Go to import, and import the database you have just exported.

You should now have a backup and can now demolish db1.

Comment: No not that one, I know that but what I mean is automatic backup yeah, so that what ever changes I make, it will automatically reflect on my backup datbase.